# estimated marginal mean in linear mixed model in spss

Tags: mixed-model

in a linear mixed model with multiple categorical predictors, I am particularly interested in examining the effect of one.

The multiple pairwise comparisons give me the estimated marginal mean (difference). I googled the definition for that, and also in the footnote of the SPSS, it says the estimated marginal mean is calculated at a certain value of the covariate (the continuous predictor included in the model). I am wondering what values of the other categorical predictors in the model are used in the estimated marginal mean calculation. And what does the marginal mean? I guess E(Y|X) with X being this particular categorical predictor, then the calculation is simply the average of predicted Y at each level of the X???